# WP7 - IsolatedStorageSettings using IF STATEMENTS?

Tags: windows-phone-7, if-statement, settings, isolatedstorage

i was just playing around with the isolated storage settings in my app and i decided to add these options: Alphabetically, Newsets to oldest and Oldest to newest. all these values are stored in a listpicker and they save and load fine but the error is that when i add more if statements it wont work. e.g. this is what wont work:

```
 Try
        Dim ListOrder As Byte = CByte(AppSettings("OrderNotes"))
        If ListOrder = 1 Then
            AscendingOrder()
        ElseIf ListOrder = 1 Then
            NewestOldest()
        ElseIf ListOrder = 2 Then
            OldestNewest()
        End If
    Catch ex As KeyNotFoundException
        AppSettings.Save()
    End Try
```

This will work:

```
Try
        Dim ListOrder As Byte = CByte(AppSettings("OrderNotes"))
        If ListOrder = 1 Then
            AscendingOrder()
        ElseIf ListOrder = 2 Then
            NewestOldest()
        End If
    Catch ex As KeyNotFoundException
        AppSettings.Save()
    End Try
```

Seems that only if it's either If or else. can't be elseif else if else if... so on.
Is there a way to solve this? so i can choose more than 2 options.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are the first two IFs both testing ListOrder = 1 ???

Comment: basically ListOrder is checking for the Listpicker's index thats why its 1 and 2 and 0. Like if ListOrder = 0 then message will show saying "1st item listpicker"

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Ahaha doesn't matter. I got it solved. it was a simple solution. i just had to double check the code. Thanks for your input though :D

Comment: What was the issue? Please edit the question and let us know. THanks.

Comment: The issue was that if i used a general if statement my code would work but if i used multiple if statements in one if statement e.g. else if it wouldn't work but it managed to get it working because there was an error in my code i had to correct.